# BMP180 sensor with BLE112 module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, i2c

I've been trying to measure temperature and pressure using BMP180 using my BLE112 module from Bluegiga. I connected SDA to pin P1_6 and clock to P1_7 according to the BGScript documentation. Whatever i do i can't get anything pushed to my characteristic... all the time it's equal to 0. I try to proceed as it is mentioned in the BMP180 datasheet.. starting with reading calibration.

This is my hardware.xml: [link](http://pastebin.com/uNvtWxDM)

temperature_sensor.bgs: [link](http://pastebin.com/s0THnCGV)

There is much comments in the code since i am trying to check if i can read anything.. I am using 
B-BLE application on android..

If someone could explain me on how to read teamperature or point any mistakes it would be coool!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late response.
bmp 180 works with serial data(SDA) and SCL(serial clock) which called I2C. 
on your microcontroller you are using check the specific pin named SCL and SDA. each MCU have a particular pin dedicated for I2C connection.
also, are you using a library? check whether the library support ur MCU, better still use arduino and adafuit bmp180 library it will be easy to solve your problem.